# Сохранение формы JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Имеется небольшое приложение, написанное с помощью JavaFX и FXML. В нем добавляются поля в listView.

Вопрос: возможно ли сохранить fxml файл так, чтобы добавленные поля остались?

То есть вопрос сводится к тому, реально ли достать измененный fxml формы и заменить им старый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно.

Идея заключается в том, что вам необходимо отображать данные в `listView`, которые могут сериализоваться. При закрытии ( или в какой момент вам нужно сохранение формы), вы должны сериализовать полностью вашу форму ( fxml легко сериализуется, это обычная xml) и ваши данные из `listView`.